# OnBindViewHolder creates new new instances of the dynamic item-views on scrolling to and fro

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have many similar cases, when I reach to the end and return back then my options of radiogroup and checkboxes adds one more instance of it.

eg;

radio button options before scrolling "
option1
option 2  " after scrolling I have "option1 option2  option1 option2  "  and so on..

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {

```
    final MyData mData = dataList.get(position);
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case 1:
            holder.textView0.setText(mData.getText());
            final int radioCount = mData.getTextFields().size();
            for (int i = 0; i < radioCount; i++) {
                RadioButton radio = new RadioButton(context);
                radio.setId(View.generateViewId());
                radio.setText(mData.getTextFields().get(i).getName());

                holder.radioGroup.addView(radio);
                radio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View view) {
                       //do something

                    }
                });
            }

            break;

        case 2: holder.textView1.setText(mData.getText());


            List<Object> selectList1= new ArrayList<>() ;          
            int Option_Count = mData.getTextFields().size();

            for (int i = 0; i < Option_Count; i++) {
                final TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
                row.setId(i);
                row.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                        String joined="";
                        if (b) {
                            selectList1.add((String) compoundButton.getText());

                            joined = TextUtils.join(", ", selectList1);


                        } else {
                            selectList1.remove((String) compoundButton.getText());
                            joined = TextUtils.join(", ", selectList1);

                        }


                        if(b){

             
                        } }
                });
                checkBox.setId(i);
                checkBox.setText(mData.getTextFields().get(i).getLabel());
                row.addView(checkBox);
                holder.linearLayout1.addView(row);

            }

            break;


    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard behaviour of the RecyclerView. Holders are reusable, when user scrolls, the `onBindViewHolder()` is called and radio buttons are added again.

The question is, how to make it right? You can initialize your views in `onCreateViewHolder()`. Is it possible for you? I don't know your data model. For example, you can add your radio buttons etc. in each constructor of your custom Viewholder class.

Comment: I cant initialize views in 'onCreateViewHolder'' because I need position for data. Can I clear my views on scrolling. Is that possible.